# Spring Data many-to-many, fetching all entities whose relationship does not contain items

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following relation:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "User")
    public class User {
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "user_group",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
        )
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
     .......
}
```

So I have User <--> Group many-to-many relation.

I need to fetch all users that do not have associations with groups at all - get all users
whose `groups` list is empty.

Is there a way to fetch users like that with a usage of spring data?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch the users who don't have groups, then try the below method in UserRepository.

```
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {

    Optional<List<User>> findAllByGroupsEmpty();
}
```

By above method, spring data jpa will fetch the users who groups are empty.

Comment: Also, if you want save the Groups while inserting user you need add Cascade, @ManyToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: You should not use `Optional` of a Java Collection as return value. If no elements are found then empty `List` has to be returned